# How to change QLineSeries width?

Tags: qt, qchart, qpen

I need to set width of `QLineSeries`
I do

```
QPen pen = series->pen();
pen.setWidth(1);
series->setPen(pen);
```

And it works  but color is changed to black. What do I need to do to set only  the width?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify brush with needed color. F.e.

```
QPen pen = series->pen();
pen.setWidth(1);
pen.setBrush(QBrush("red")); // or just pen.setColor("red");
series->setPen(pen);
```

Update:

> But can I set width without missing current color?

It can be done if you will set pen after `addSeries()` call. Because `defaultColor` (color of your pen) in your case is just (1,0,0,0), default color (this kind of blue color on the plot) depends on chosen theme and appears after you call `chart->addSeries(series);` So only way to achieve what you want is smth like next:

```
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series); // addSeries must be called first

QPen pen = series->pen();
pen.setWidth(1);
series->setPen(pen);
```

Comment: I do it now as you answered. But can I set width without missing current color?